# Where can I find a list of Ubuntu global events in the world?

Tags: community, events

I'd like to go to an event of Ubuntu. I don't care about the country or month.

Is there any wiki/web page where I could see all the (specific) Ubuntu events in the world?
Just global events like the Ubuconla.org or Ubucon.de

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you thinking about community events, global events, developer events, team meetings, etc? There is no UbuntuConf that I know of, though Ubuntu folks sometimes show up at conferences.

Comment: Good point! There are events for the LoCo teams in the portal: http://loco.ubuntu.com/events/ Just Global events, like the ubuconla.org or ubucon.de

Comment: Well, I upvoted this because *I* would like to see that list, but it doesn't seem one exists, no matter where I look. I'd be happy to create an Ubuntu Wiki page if you want to collect a list ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these sites with Ubucon listings:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubucon

http://ubucon.org/